# Function changing global variable only in function, not in class

Tags: ios, xcode, swift5

Whenver I assign a value to my global variable, it changes only in the function, and then it doesn't change in the whole class. Here is my code for the function:

```
var destinationCord = CLCoordinate2d()
func getAddress(address: String) {
            let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
            geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { (placemarks, error) in
                guard let placemarks = placemarks, let location = placemarks.first?.location
                    else{
                        print("No Location Found")
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No Location Found, Please enter an valid address or location", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
    //                    self.textFieldForAddress.text = ""
                        self.present(alert, animated: true)
                        return
                    }
                print(location.coordinate)
                self.destinationCord = location.coordinate
                print("destinationCord: \(self.destinationCord)")
            }
    }
```

Here is where I am calling it:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        
        for address in Constants.Storyboard.addressHardCode {
            let sourceLocation = (locationManager.location?.coordinate)!
            getAddress(address: address)
            print(destinationCord)
            let coord1 = CLLocation(latitude: sourceLocation.latitude, longitude: sourceLocation.longitude)
            let coord2 = CLLocation(latitude: destinationCord.latitude, longitude: destinationCord.longitude)
            let distance = coord1.distance(from: coord2)
            if (distance <= 8046) {
                cell.textLabel?.text = Constants.Storyboard.food[Constants.Storyboard.addressHardCode.firstIndex(of: address)!]
                
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
```

When I print destination cord in cellForRowAt, it always returns (0, 0), but it is definitely going inside the function. It seems it is only changing the value locally, but not sure how to fix. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which variable are you saying is not changed? How is it not changed (what code tries to use it?) The term 'global' is not used to describe a variable that is a member of a class. So including the declaration of the variable you expect to change may also be helpful.

Comment: Just added it, hope this helps.

Comment: By any chance, are you seeing the print from `cellForRowAt` before the one from `getAddress`?  It looks as if you're calling an asynchronous function but expecting to see the result immediately.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right. Is there also a reason why my array's length is 3 but it is printing everything 6 time? Also, do you have any ideas how to fix this, @PhillipMills?

Comment: I don't know about the 6 times (maybe cellForRowAt is called more times) but here's a blog someone wrote about a problem much like your first one: http://www.programmingios.net/you-cant-use-a-value-after-it-has-been-set-by-asyncronous-code/